# for how long is Content considered "new" by the filter criteria "Content: has new content"?

Tags: views

I'm trying to find out how Drupal uses the "has new content" filter criteria.  I'd like to create a View that only shows the latest content on the site, but not sure what is going to be returned.  24 hours, 7 days, 30 days?

I don't see any way to set the duration, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 7, the Views module uses the [NODE_NEW_LIMIT](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/constant/NODE_NEW_LIMIT/7). If you look at the code used by the [views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node!views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp.inc/class/views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp/7) class, which filters the new content, you will notice the following code (in [views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp::query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node!views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp.inc/function/views_handler_filter_history_user_timestamp::query/7)).

```
  // Hey, Drupal kills old history, so nodes that haven't been updated
  // since NODE_NEW_LIMIT are bzzzzzzzt outta here!

  $limit = REQUEST_TIME - NODE_NEW_LIMIT;

  $this->ensure_my_table();
  $field = "$this->table_alias.$this->real_field";
  $node = $this->query->ensure_table('node', $this->relationship);

  $clause = '';
  $clause2 = '';
  if (module_exists('comment')) {
    $ncs = $this->query->ensure_table('node_comment_statistics', $this->relationship);
    $clause = ("OR $ncs.last_comment_timestamp > (***CURRENT_TIME*** - $limit)");
    $clause2 = "OR $field < $ncs.last_comment_timestamp";
  }
```

The same constant is used from [node_mark()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_mark/7), which the function that returns a value used to decide if outputting *updated*, or *new* in a list of nodes, such as the one shown by the Tracker module.

```
  if (!isset($cache[$nid])) {
    $cache[$nid] = node_last_viewed($nid);
  }
  if ($cache[$nid] == 0 && $timestamp > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
    return MARK_NEW;
  }
  elseif ($timestamp > $cache[$nid] && $timestamp > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
    return MARK_UPDATED;
  }
  return MARK_READ;
```

The value of the `NODE_NEW_LIMIT` is the number of seconds in 30 days.

To notice that when you visit the node, "new" is not anymore shown.

[image: before]

[image: after visiting the first two nodes]

Comment: Where is the constant set?  If I wanted to make it 7 days insetad, for example.

Comment: It's defined in node.module. I don't know how you can redefine that constant, and use your value in all the places.