# Views: adding "new" image when published date < 1 month

Tags: views

In a table view of nodes i want to add a tiny "New" image only when a node is published < 1 month ago. 
Is there a way to achieve this without using PHP? If not, is there an easy way and what PHP should i insert? 
I was hoping for a little module to get the job done, but haven't found anything.

Thanx, 
Cas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is always going to be in date order, then it can be done without PHP by using a View with an attachment. See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/add-class-to-new-posts-with-views/64154#64154) for an explanation of how to do that.

If the list is not sorted in date order, PHP may be the way to go. (Though I'd be delighted to be contradicted.) You'll need the Views PHP module installed.

- Add the `Content: Post date` to your list of fields. If you don't want it displayed set the 'Exclude from display' check box. Displayed or not, it's needed.
- Add a 'Global: PHP' field to your list of fields. In the **Value code** box, insert the following snippet:

  ```
  $interval = time()-  $data->node_created;
  $days = round($interval/(60*60*24));
  return $days < 30 ? $days : 0;
  ```

This snippet grabs the value of the `Post date` field from the database query that the view has executed. It then works out the number of seconds difference between the post date and the current time. It converts the seconds into days. If the post is less than 30 days old it returns the number of days as a field value, otherwise it returns 0. (It could just return 0 or 1, but returning the value could be useful in some cases.)

- In the No Results Behaviour section check the boxes for 'Count the number 0 as empty', 'Hide if empty' and 'Hide rewriting if empty'. This means when the PHP returns zero, nothing will be displayed.
- In the Rewrite Results section, insert whatever output you want when the node is less than 30 days old. In the question you talk about an image, so maybe put in something such as `<img src="your image">`.

**Additional Notes**

If you want to use different date fields etc. you can work out what to put in the PHP by switching on the display of the SQL query in preview. (See the Views settings tab from the main Views page.)

If you want a bit more control over your output, you can use the **Output code** box. For example the following code will put a red 'new!' label against new fields. When doing this you don't want to also have Rewrite Results set.

```
<?php if ($value) echo '<p style="color:red">new!</p>' ?>
```

This code checks to see if the result of the earlier PHP code is TRUE (and not zero is TRUE). If it is is displays the red 'new!'

Comment: Thanx again for your invaluable help! It all works perfectly and i chose to use the **new!** text instead of an image because it shows better in a table view. But somehow an image does not show anyway. I triple-checked the syntax, path and filename, but all i get is a little blue ? in a box telling me the image can't be found. I checked the element telling me the path/filename is right. The same happens with other fields in the same view i want to rewrite as an image. I use the same syntax in a Flag where it works OK. I wonder if this has something to do with Views settings?

Comment: Forget my last question, found the path-problem. It seems that Views needs the whole path (/mydir/sites/default/files/myimages/myimg.png) where the Flags module only needs a relative path (sites/default/files/myimages/myimg.png). Confusing.

Comment: Good to hear answer was helpful and you tracked down source of yr image path issue. To help other users do consider marking the answer as correct.